# xpath cannot get anchor href value

Tags: php, xpath

I'm having issues getting the `anchor href` from an `xpath query`.

Here is the query:

```
$hrefxpath = $xpath->query('//*[@id="content"]/article[1]/article[1]/div/h2/a[@href]');
foreach($hrefxpath as $item){
  var_dump($item->nodeValue);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="content">
   <article>
        <article>
           <div>
             <h2>
                <a href="hrefvalue">Something Awesome</a>
             </h2>
           </div>
        </article>
   </article>
</div>
```

The result is `Something Awesome` **but there is no href value.**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is, because you just output nodeValue. Add

```
var_dump($item->getAttribute('href'));
```

to get the attribute of the DOMElement.